# Convert string containing a date in multiple formats to a string containing a date in the "CCYYMMDD" format

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, date, format

I have a string which contains a date and time. Date is in any of the following formats: 
 
"**M/D/YYYY**" or "**MM/D/YYYY**" or "**M/DD/YYYY**" or "**MM/DD/YYYY**". 

And time is either in: 
"**hh:mm:ss**" or "**h:mm:ss**". 

The string is retrieved from SQL Server in C# code.

How do I convert this into a string containing date in the format "**CCYYMMDD**"?

Comment: Do you want to convert it in SQL Server or in the client code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var inputDate = "4/28/2006 12:39:32:429AM";

        //1 - parse into date parts
        char[] delimiterChars = { '/' };

        string[] dateParts = inputDate.Split(delimiterChars);
        var month = int.Parse(dateParts[0].ToString());
        var day = int.Parse(dateParts[1].ToString()); 
        var year = 0;

        string yearString = dateParts[2].ToString();

        //strip of the time for the year part
        if (yearString.Length > 5)
            year = int.Parse(yearString.Substring(0, 4));

        //2 - Create date object
        DateTime testDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);

        //3 - format date
        var outputDate = testDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

        Console.WriteLine("Input date: " + inputDate);
        Console.WriteLine("Output date: " + outputDate);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

You can refer to MSDN for formatting dates [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) . You may also want to do some validation to ensure you're getting a valid date from SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks @Vince. Simplest way to validate would be?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this way is better.  I don't know what I was thinking before.. use the DateTime.TryParse method validate if the string is a date.  If TryParse comes back as false, the string is not in a valid date format.  The format you are expecting in your requirement are valid date formats.

```
        DateTime date;

        var inputDate = "4/28/2006 12:39:32";
        var outputDate = "Could not format the date.  The input date is not in a correct date format!";

        if (DateTime.TryParse(inputDate,out date))
        {
            outputDate = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Input date: " + inputDate);
        Console.WriteLine("Output date: " + outputDate);

        Console.ReadLine();
```